# Corrupt Blob triggered by mediaRecorder.requestData()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio, web-audio-api

I have an issues with Audio Web API. Why when I use [`mediaRecorder.requestData();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/requestData) instead [`MediaRecorder.stop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/stop) of  the Blob retrieve from [`dataavailable` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/ondataavailable) is "corrupt".

See here an [example of output](https://output.jsbin.com/domeyutuba/3)

Answer (score 1):

Only the first blob from `ondataavailable` event will contain [file signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures). The rest will not contain it, hence it is not playable. You need to concatenate the blobs into one big blob.

Quoting from [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=898771)

> My understanding of the spec is that this bug is invalid; i.e., individual blobs are not individually decodable in general; they must be concatenated to produce a usable resource. And that's what we implemented.